# How Do I provide client support in sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, sftp

I have Target board where sshd is a daemon which will set the sftp-server and listen to client trying to connect to board using sftp protocol.But there when I try to connect to other machine from target board sftp is not working .I mean wanted to set my board as sftp client.

Is there any way to setup the above(Setting STFP-clinet) in sshd daemon??

Comment: Or do you mean the target should be a sftp _proxy_, i.e. you connect to it with sftp client and it connects to the real server on your behalf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ssh server and ssh client are independent components. A sftp client simply needs the `sftp` binary. Ssh server is not required on the computer where the client is and often is not installed there at all.

The server you want to connect to of course needs to have a ssh server with the sftp-server set.

Comment: We already had stfp-server working fine on our Target but we have requirement of getting sftp client on same target,Wanted to know how can this sftp clinet as daemon??

Comment: @AMIT: Whether you have sftp server working there or not is **irrelevant**. `sftp` _client_ is a simple application, not a daemon. You just need to put the application on the target.

Comment: would like to ask one more thing,Do vsftp and sftp have any relationship.Is thery any Interdependency between these two??

Comment: @AMIT: I've never heard of `vsftp`. Quick web search suggests it is a ftp server and since sftp is completely different protocol from ftp, I don't think there is a relation.